# Restrict number of instances of a build in the queue

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is it possible to limit the number of instances of a single build configuration in the queue?

When a build is triggered I would like it to be added to the queue but if there are more than x instances of that build on the queue already then the oldest instance of the build in the queue is removed as well as the new instance being added.

Is there a plugin that does this?

Comment: It looks as if this is a [WON'T FIX](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7709) issue. But, [this might do something](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Block+queued+job+plugin), but then again it has zero installs...

Comment: @jamesthetester have you figured the answer for your question? i too have the same question. please share if you have some answers

Comment: @divine am afraid not, I moved away from Jenkins a few years ago and I think I still had that issue, sorry!

Comment: Moved away from Jenkins? What do you use now?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this plugin personally, but give it a try. I think it throttles the maximum no. of jobs instances in a given node or globally.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin

Comment: I use that plugin to throttle the number of builds running but it doesn't have any effect on the number of builds in a queue (still very useful though)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want *one* instance in the queue: set the job to be **parameterized** (e.g., just a bogus boolean parameter with a default value). It considers copies of the same job in the queue to be duplicates if they have the same parameter values, so I don't think it would queue a second one.

If you want to limit the queue size for a given job to some other number, I don't know how; I suspect the right approach would depend on your use case, and if it's unusual enough there might not be a simple solution. (I haven't personally encountered situations where queuing multiple jobs makes sense *but only* up to some specific number: if you want them queued at all then I suspect you care about all of them. Queue length of 0 or 1 has some obvious applications though.)